# Invalid Argument Supply for foreach

Tags: php, foreach

I have a problem in my foreach. I am trying to get the data by category. I have some popular category on my home page. I want when the user click on the catname its show related jobs of that category its fine when data exist but data not found its give me an error `invalid argument Supply for foreach`.

Here is my controller:

```
public function catwise($catname){
        $data['jobs'] = $this->edituser_model->getBlogByname($catname); 
        $this->load->view('locwise' , $data);           
    }
```

and my Model is:

```
public function getBlogByname($catname){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('catname', $catname);
        $query = $this->db->get('jobs');

      if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->result();
      } else {
        return false;
      }

    }
```

and my view is:

```
<?php if(count($jobs)): ?>
   <?php foreach ($jobs as  $row): ?> 

      <div class="job-box">
           <div class="company-logo">
      </div>

      <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <div class="alert alert-success alert-2" role="alert">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                           Recently Posted Jobs in <?php echo $row->catname?>
                        Category</div>
        <div class="row">
                <div class="job-box">

                    <div class="description">
                        <div class="float-left">
                            <h5 class="title"><a href="<?php echo site_url('candidate/jobs_detail/' .$row->id);?>"><?php echo $row->job_title?></a></h5>
                            <div class="candidate-listing-footer">
                            <ul> 
                                    <li><i class="flaticon-pin">&nbsp;</i><?php echo $row->location?></li>
                                    <li><i class="flaticon-money">&nbsp;</i><?php echo $row->salary?></li>
                                    <li><i class="flaticon-work">&nbsp;</i><?php echo $row->timing?></li>
                                    <!--<li><i class="flaticon-honor">&nbsp;</i><?php echo $jobs->qualification?></li>
                                     <li><i class="flaticon-notepad">&nbsp;</i><?php echo $jobs->experience?></li>-->
                            </ul>&nbsp; 
                            <h6>Deadline:<?php echo $row->deadline?></h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="div-right">
                            <a href="<?php echo site_url('candidate/edit/' .$row->id);?>" class="apply-button">Apply Now</a>
                            <!--<a href="#"><i class="flaticon-heart favourite"></i></a>--> 
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
                       </div>
                       </div><!--end row--> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div>
 <?php endforeach ?>
 <?php else: ?>
  <span class="text-danger">No jobs are currently active at the moment. Please check again later. Or to look for more jobs on our website please click <a href="<?= site_url('Welcome/job_list');?>">here!</a></span><br>
 <?php endif;?>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Many Thanks:
Junaid Amin

Answer (score 2):

When your model returns `boolean`, i.e. `false`, `count(false)` (`true` also) equal to `1`.

```
echo count(false);
```

https://3v4l.org/ChEDK

You should return an empty array, like `return [];`.